# What is $\lim _{(x, y)\rightarrow(0, 0)} (x^{\frac{1}{3}}y^2)/(x+y^3)$?

Tags: calculus, limits, multivariable-calculus

Fix $x=-y^3$.

$\lim _{y\rightarrow0} ((-y^3)^{\frac{1}{3}}y^2)/(-y^3+y^3)$

Which results in dividing by zero. Does this mean the limit does not exist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to compute the limit through a path that is not contained in the domain of the function, it's no good. You can look instead at the path $x = y^3$, which gives $$\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{x^{1/3} x^{2/3}}{x+x} = \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{x}{2x} = \frac{1}{2}.$$This tells us that **if** the limit exists, it must be $1/2$. However, looking at the line $x = 0$ gives the limit as zero. Hence it does not exist.

Comment: If you don't mind, can you guide me through your train of thought that made you pick $x=y^3$? I can't see my self coming up with this on my own.

Comment: Sure. I thought of $x = y^3$ because that would make the denominator very simple: $2x$. Then I'd look at what happens in the numerator and hope that it worked. If not, I'd think of something else.

Answer (score 0):

First, find the limit by fixing $x=0$.

Then, find the limit by substitution $x=y^3$.

Compare these two limits and then conclude.